# Return value for function is not working correctly. How to set up correct return value for function checkIfExist()?

Tags: javascript, extendscript, adobe-premiere

I am writing a script for Premiere pro where I can add markers in the timeline and export a still for each marker in one go. However, when I write a function to check if the still has been previously created, the functions tells me it finds the previously created still, but then still creates a new one.
So basically: Function returns true, but still executes the else{}

```
    //checks if the frame that is about to be exported already exists 
        if(checkIfExist(app.project.rootItem, outputFile)){
            alert("frame already exists");
        }else{
        //This is where the actual still gets created and imported
            activeSequence.exportFramePNG(time, outputFileName);
        //here the previously created item gets moved to the appropriate bin (This is working great ATM)
            moveToBin(outputFile);
       }
    }
}
//This function is meant to check if an item exists in the project bin. It does this by looping though all the items in the array from the start. 
function checkIfExist(currentItem, name){
    for(var i = 0; i<currentItem.children.numItems; i++){
        currentChild = currentItem.children[i];
        if(currentChild.name.toUpperCase() === name.toUpperCase()){
            alert("Found:   " + currentChild.name);
            return true;
        }if(currentChild.type == ProjectItemType.BIN){
            checkIfExist(currentChild, name);
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Very likely that checkIfExist runs more than the number of times you you think it runs. It is true but then runs again and it is false and then your else runs too

Comment: thank you for your response. How can I check if it does? And if so, how do I solve it?

Comment: You can check by placing a console.log Inside the function and check if it logs more then once. Maybe also add one in you if statements inside the function. Possible solution in my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it happens because of the recursion  you do:

```
 if(currentChild.type == ProjectItemType.BIN){
            checkIfExist(currentChild, name);
 }
```

If this one gets kicked off before you can return true, you will start to run the function for a second time.

Now the first run can return a true, while the second (or even 3th, or 4th, etc) can return false and thus creating a new one, while also finding it.

Also if possible try to use arr.find or arr.findIndex and check if the value is -1 (or not found). This will make your code shorter, cleaner and less open for errors :)

But this will not work for nested arrays. Then you need to make an other function to first make a flat copy that includes all nested array before you do the arr.find or arr.findIndex. Still think that is the better solution.

You can use this to make nested array into a flat one:

```
let arr1 = [1,2,3,[1,2,3,4, [2,3,4]]];

function flattenDeep(arr1) {
   return arr1.reduce((acc, val) => Array.isArray(val) ? acc.concat(flattenDeep(val)) : acc.concat(val), []);
}
flattenDeep(arr1);// [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: What a good idea! Will def try. I will let you know if it worked.

Comment: Sorry for the edits, was puzzling a bit myself ;) But I think the recursion is the thing that give you the trouble you describe.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I def made some progress. However, turns out that .find and .findIndex are not implemented in Extendscript. From the Adobe forums: "The primary reason that some of those functions do not exist, is because ExtendScript is based on the ECMA-262 standard. Very old Javascript, and I believe not all of it is implemented."